# pls correct my mistake

Tags: sql, oracle, alter

alter table medicine
rename price to purchase_price ;

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you at all tried looking into the documents or help file before posting a question.

Comment: i dont ask any question but why ? i dont find answer for my question

Comment: Your question was closed because the problem was caused by a minor syntax issue that you could and should have solved yourself by reading the manual - in this case, the [Oracle SQL Reference Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/toc.htm). Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

[Syntax](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/alter_table.php) for `rename`-ing a column is

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN old_name TO new_name;
```

You should use

```
alter table medicine rename column price to purchase_price
```

Comment: If you want to answer a question then its better you edit the question so that its readable to others as well. Don't just jump onto the answers

Comment: i am not sure what your problem is, in reading the question?

Comment: if you are so sure then why did you put the question on hold? I think it is not a good practice that you also put on hold and you also answer the question.

Comment: it is better you do what you feel is right. easier to suggest i guess.

Comment: Exactly I am doing what is better here. Nina is completely new to here. So nina has got to learn about how to ask questions here and without seniors like you not giving a suggestion will not be a easy journey.